# Late 70's/early 80's fantasy movie similar to Beastmaster

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember the name of a He-Man/Beastmaster type movie from the late 70's or early 80's

The only scene I can remember was of a blond, shirtless, He-Man type character who had a silver amulet necklace thing melt while on his chest. I believe he was on his back in the sand? Maybe after a space ship crash

After searching the Internet, the character reminds me of a young, long-haired Dolph Lundgren but I'm reasonably sure it's not him.

Comment: [Laserblast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sn7Z6b9KxdE)?

Answer (score 7):

**[*Yor: The Hunter From the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yor,_the_Hunter_from_the_Future)**

**Date:** 1983

**Shirtless He-Man/Beastmaster/Blond Dolph Lundgren type:** Yor!

**Space ship:** The Overlord's spaceship.

**Necklace:** Um...

**Sand:** Typical desert barbarians setting of the genre.

[image: Yor promotional poster]

[Reviewed here on scifi.blogoverflow.com](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/03/jacks-bad-movies-yor-the-hunter-from-the-future/)

[image: Still from Yor]

Comment: Good guess! Yor definitely had an amulet, but I don't remember it melting. There's a review of Yor on the site's blog - might want to add as a link.

Comment: http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/03/jacks-bad-movies-yor-the-hunter-from-the-future/

Answer (score 0):

flash gordon, 1980, starring samuel j. jones

Comment: can you provide more detail as to why this might be the correct answer? Screen capture or script details that correlate with OP details?